# Uso de variables de un archivo llamado con Include

Tags: php

Nuevamente necesitando de su ayuda, esta vez necesito utilizar unas variables que se encuentran dentro de un archivo **equipoTrabajo.php** el cual mando a llamar desde **proyectos.php** mediante un `include`. Dichas variables necesito colocarlas dentro de un `array` pero no sé de qué manera extraerlas de su archivo de origen. Les dejo el código esperando se entienda y puedan ayudarme:

**equipoTrabajo.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($conex)) {
    //Código...
}
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'f') !== null)
    $f = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'f');
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id') !== null)
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
if ($puedeEditar) {
    //Código...
    if($f == 'n'){
        //Código...
    }
    elseif ($f == 'n2') {
//VARIABLES QUE NECESITO - $personaID, $rol, $tipoRH...
        $rol = 5;
        $empleado_id = $us_id =  0;
        $personaID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'personaID'); //$personaID
        if(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'rol') !== null)
            $rol = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'rol'); //rol
        $tipoRH = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'tipo'); //tipoRH
        if($tipoRH == 1){
            //Código...
        }
        else{
            //Código...
        }
        if($us_id > 0){
            //Código...
        }
    }
    elseif($f == 'e'){
        //Código...
    }
    elseif($f == 'e2'){
//VARIABLES QUE NECESITO - $idEmp, $rol, $activo...
        $idEmp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'idEmp'); //idEmp
        $rol = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'rol'); //$rol
        $activo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'activo'); //$activo
        if(!empty($rol) && !empty($activo)){
            //Código...
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**proyectos.php**

```
<?php
if (!$tieneAcceso) {
    //Código...
}
if (!isset($conex)) $conex = new SafeMySQL ();
if ($puedeEditar) {
    //Código...
}
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op1') !== null) {
    //Código...
}
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op2') !== null) {
    //Código...
}
if ($opcion1 == 'newPr' && $puedeEditar) {
    //Código...
}
//ESTA PARTE DE AQUÍ ES EL CONTROLADOR...
elseif ($opcion1 == 'edit') {
    if (null !== filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id')) {
        //Código...
    }
    if (empty($nProyecto))
        die('Se requiere clave de registro');
    if($idObtenido != $nProyecto){
        //Código...
    }
    else {
        //Código...
    }
    if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proyecto') !== null) {
        if (!$puedeEditar) {
            //Código...
        }
        $proyecto2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proyecto', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $cliente_id2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cliente_id');
        $estatus2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estatus');
        $objetivo2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'objetivo');
        $color2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'color');
//ARRAY EN EL QUE QUIERO AGREGAR LAS VARIABLES OBTENIDAS DEL ARCHIVO equipoTrabajo.php - $registro
        $registro = array(); //$registro
        $registro['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id2;
        $registro['estatus'] = $estatus2;
        $registro['objetivo'] = $objetivo2;
        $registro['color'] = $color2;
        if (!empty($proyecto2)) {
            //Código...
        }
        if ($result === true) {
            //Código...
        }
        else {
            //Código...
        }
    }
//ESTA PARTE DE AQUÍ ES LA VISTA...
    if($puedeEditar){
        //Código...
    }
    if($puedeElim){
        //Código...
    }
    if($_SESSION['proy_p2'] > 0){
        //Código...
    }
    $idTab = 'eProy';
    iniModulo("Proyectos - $proyecto");
    abreFormTab($idTab, $aTabs, $elpost);
    abreTab($idTab, 1);
    abreBloque('Datos generales');
    label1('*', 'Departamento', $_Depto->getName());
    inputText('<', 'Proyecto', 'proyecto', $proyecto, '', array('placeholder' => 'Proyecto', 'required' => ''));
    showSelect('>', 'Estatus', 'estatus', $estatus, $estatusProyecto, 'Seleccione el estatus del Proyecto', $propC1);
    showSelect('<', 'Cliente', 'cliente_id', $cliente_id, $aClientes, 'Seleccionar Cliente', $propC1);
    inputText('>', 'Color', 'color', $color, '', array('placeholder' => 'Color', 'id'=>'colorpicker'));
    textArea('*', 'objetivo', 'Objetivo', $objetivo, 'Objetivo del proyecto', $pCDetalle);
    cierraBloque();
    cierraTab();
    $id = $nProyecto;
    abreTab($idTab, 2);
    abreBloque('Equipo de trabajo');
    abreDiv('divProET');
//INCLUDE CON EL CUAL MANDO A LLAMAR EL ARCHIVO equipoTrabajo.php...
    include ('equipoTrabajo.php');
    cierraDiv();
    cierraBloque();
    cierraTab();
    if($_SESSION['proy_p2'] > 0){
        abreTab($idTab, 3);
        abreBloque('Lista de archivos');
        abreDiv('divAdjP');
        require 'proy_adj.php';
        cierraDiv();
        cierraBloque();
        cierraTab();
    }
    cierraFormTab($btnEnviar, $urlList, '', $btnElimP);
}
?>
```

Los archivos son mucho más extensos pero traté de quitar las partes que consideré no eran necesarias.

Las variables que necesito agregar en el `array` son para mandarlas como parámetro a una función que edita el Proyecto y a su vez registra cambios en un historial.

Estos archivos no son míos pero me encuentro trabajando en ellos, se han ido modificando a lo largo de unos cuantos años, por eso es parte programación estructurada y parte POO.

De antemano gracias(:

Comment: Primero que nada hablas de que incluyes un fichero en otro usando la directiva include, no se ve por ningún lado y  segundo el uso de las variables declaradas en uno de los fichero para ser usadas en el segundo tampoco se ve, solo se aprecia su declaración en el primer archivo.

Comment: Puse un comentario en el cual digo donde está el `include` y las variables que necesito no sé ni cómo usarlas en el segundo fichero, por eso puse un comentario donde quiero usar esas funciones.

Answer (score 1):

El `include` lo puedes incluir antes de esta parte de tu código, suponiendo que `$cliente_id2` sea una variable definida en `equipoTrabajo.php`, (por nombrar una variable).

**Tu archivo:**

```
//ARRAY EN EL QUE QUIERO AGREGAR LAS VARIABLES OBTENIDAS DEL ARCHIVO equipoTrabajo.php - $registro

    $registro = array(); //$registro
    $registro['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id2;
    $registro['estatus'] = $estatus2;
    $registro['objetivo'] = $objetivo2;
    $registro['color'] = $color2;
```

**Como podrías implementarlo:**

```
include ('equipoTrabajo.php');
//ARRAY EN EL QUE QUIERO AGREGAR LAS VARIABLES OBTENIDAS DEL ARCHIVO equipoTrabajo.php - $registro

    $registro = array(); //$registro
    $registro['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id2;
    $registro['estatus'] = $estatus2;
    $registro['objetivo'] = $objetivo2;
    $registro['color'] = $color2;
```

De esta manera puedes utilizar las variables, funciones que estén definidas en el fichero incluido.

> **Nota**
>  El interprete PHP lee los ficheros línea a línea por esta
>   razón es recomendable incluir los ficheros antes de implementar sus
>   funciones o variables, de forma contraria arrojara variable indefinida

Comment: Funciona, sólo que ahora tengo otro problema, las variables que necesito ya puedo usarlas pero como **equipoTrabajo.php** contiene parte de la vista, ahora se ve donde no debería, afecta parte de mi otro fichero, por eso no puedo colocarlo antes

Comment: @PalomaAG no se me ocurre una forma posible en ese caso, pero una opción seria poner el código dentro de una función y ejecutarla luego cuando sea necesario su uso

Comment: Parece que hay un problema de diseño, quizá debas replantearte la organización del código y modificarla, si es posible, definiendo si `equipoTrabajo.php` pertenece al modelo, a la vista o al controlador porque si hace de modelo y de vista al mismo tiempo, o de controlador, de modelo y de vista al mismo tiempo o de controlador y de vista al mismo tiempo... al tener esa mezcla tendrás problemas de este tipo. Si `equipoTrabajo.php` muestra algo en pantalla en su flujo normal, es imposible incluirlo sin que muestre nada. El error de diseño es evidente.

Comment: El problema es que tengo que limitarme a lo que hay, puedo modificar algunas cosas y agregar otras cuantas pero mi jefe me ha dicho que use lo que ya está establecido debido a que a pesar de que está algo revuelto es funcional y si modifico ciertas cosas del código se crearía un caos, se supone que el proyecto se va a ir modificando poco a poco hasta que quede completamente como MVC pero de momento si hay muchas complicaciones. `equipoTrabajo.php` tiene tanto vista como controlador al igual que `proyectos.php`.